# Oracle DB scheduled export of table to .CSV file

Tags: database, oracle, csv

I have an application that writes to Oracle database and I would like to export this data on a schedule (every 5 minutes) to a `.CSV` file, so it can be later picked up by our IBM AS/400 server. Anyone able to assist?

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule SQL*Plus

```
# generate CSV from query
sqlplus -s -m "CSV ON DELIM ',' QUOTE ON" system/oracle@localhost/XEPDB1 @query.sql
```

Best of luck!

You can also use the [SQLcl](https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/sqldeveloper/sqlcl-20.2.0.174.1557.zip) tool for the job:

```
cat > query.sql <<EOF
set sqlformat csv
spool objects.csv
select object_id, object_name, object_type from dba_objects where rownum < 4;
spool off
exit
EOF

sqlcl -S system/oracle@localhost/XEPDB1 @query.sql
"OBJECT_ID","OBJECT_NAME","OBJECT_TYPE"
9,"I_FILE#_BLOCK#","INDEX"
38,"I_OBJ3","INDEX"
45,"I_TS1","INDEX"

cat objects.csv
"OBJECT_ID","OBJECT_NAME","OBJECT_TYPE"
9,"I_FILE#_BLOCK#","INDEX"
38,"I_OBJ3","INDEX"
45,"I_TS1","INDEX"
```

Comment: Thanks! So if I wanted to schedule a table called "TN_CI" to be exported to .CSV and saved to desktop every 5 minutes, what would be the steps to apply this code :)

Comment: You can use cron under GNU Linux or the Task Scheduler under Windows to create a scheduled task using Bjarte's answer.

Comment: @clocktwister echo "select * from TN_CI;" > query.sql

Comment: I think the issue I have now is that my DB is ver 12.1.0.2.0 and I think .CSV export is only available from 12.2? Is this correct and could you suggest a alternative if this is the case?

Comment: @clocktwister As long as you follow the client/server compatibility matrix, you can run ANY client towards the database. Yes, there is one installed together with the Oracle Database, but Oracle Client version > 12.1.0.2 can be installed into a different ORACLE_HOME.

Comment: @clocktwister I have updated my answer, SQLcl is self-contained and can be installed anywhere in your path. This tool might be the way ahead.

Comment: This looks good! In your answer could you let me know what goes where please? e.g. which past goes to the task scheduler? and would I use a .bat file to run this? You can probably guess that I am very new to this! Also when I try to run C:\sqlcl-20.2.0.174\sqlcl\bin>sql.exe -S smarteam/******@localhist/testdb @query.sql I get repeated error "ORA-12514 TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor, would you be able to advise? Thank you!

Comment: @BjarteBrandt Forgot to tag you in my commend above :)

Comment: @clocktwister If you don't specify port (hostname/SERVICE_NAME) default port is 1521, but you can contact a listener so your problem is your SERVICE_NAME "testdb". This service isn't available through the listener LISTENING on 1521. You might have multiple listeners in your environment so to be sure add port to connect-string hostname:port/SERVICE_NAME . Make sure the SERVICE_NAME is correct.